# DataNucleus Access Eclipse SchemaTool

Tags: eclipse, datanucleus

I've installed and configured the Eclipse Plugin for the DataNucleus Access Platform yet when I try to run the SchemaTool I get the following error..

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/datanucleus/store/schema/SchemaTool

it appears that the eclipse plugin is looking in an older location for the SchemaTool, it's actually at the following location:

org\datanucleus\store\rdbms\SchemaTool in datanucleus-rdbms-2.2.4.jar

Has anyone ran into this issue and have a fix for it, I'd really like to use the eclipse plugin for development.

Thanks in advance.
..Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the correct version of the Eclipse plugin for the version of DataNucleus being used. v2.x for DataNucleus v2.2, and v3.x for DataNucleus v3.0

Comment: I downloaded the eclipse plugin from the update site: http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/eclipse-update/ via the link found off the following page: http://www.datanucleus.org/project/download.html I did not see anything about versions for the plugins ?

Comment: Eclipse update allows you to "view all versions" (if you check the box)